# Is it safe to mark the CDI conversation interface as transient?

Tags: java, serialization, cdi, conversation-scope

Is the conversation interface you can inject in a @ConversationScoped bean safe to mark transient (ie. will CDI deal with it is during serialization) or I do I need a custom read/writeObject?

```
@ConversationScoped
    public class CDIConversationScopedBean implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Inject
        private transient Conversation conversation; // <<-- transient ok?
```

FindBugs is complaining about a non-transient non-serializable instance field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Yes, it is safe. Explanation:

Since the `Conversation` class doesn't implement the [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface as well the static analyzers usually complain that all the fields must be either [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) or transient even if the class is never explicitly serialized or deserialized.

Firstly, your snippet is a bit questionable, why do you implement this marker interface - so do you plan to serialize this class? You might want to add the generated or default Serial Version UID.

To solve this, make the field `transient` if you don't plan to make de/serialize the class - it's harmless and will not affect the behavior of `Conversation`. See Java 8 specification, [chapter 8.3.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3).

> Variables may be marked transient to indicate that they are not part of the persistent state of an object.

If you plan, make `Conversation` implement [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and treat its fields in the same way.

Comment: The conversation interface is a CDI provided interface, how can I make it implement Serializable as you suggest?

Comment: You can't serialize a class that doesn't implement the `Serializable` interface, but you can wrap it in a class that does - use a decorator. Again: Do you need to serialize it? If not, make the field `transient`. Why do you implement `Serializable` then? The real question is here: to serialize or not to serialize.

Comment: The Serializable marker is implemented because the CDI spec requires that passivating beans like @ConversationScoped implement it.

Comment: Well, it means you don't serialize the class, then use the `transient` keyword and FindBugs stops complaining. See my answer which explains why "is transient ok?".

Comment: My understanding is the class can be serialized by the container at any time so I don't understand what you mean by "you don't serialize the class"

Comment: It does? It does not work in this way. The container won't serialize what is not `Serializable` anyway. Then the only question is whether you plan to de/serialize it.

Comment: Some containers will attempt it and throw an exception if you don't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847669/saving-objects-in-servlet-session-and-java-io-notserializableexception

Comment: One of the answers at the linked question starts with: "Serialization is attempted not only when objects are persisted to hard disk, but also when transferred to another node in distributed environment." - the serialization does not start without your intention. The question again is: do you plan to serialize or not?

Comment: Given it depends on the servlet container and other settings which may or may not be turned on in a given set up, to be on the safe side, yes I want to serialize it.